# Using regex for address range

Tags: sed

I have the following file:

```
$ cat file
> First line
> Second line
> Third line
> Fourth and last line
> First line
> Second line
> Third line
> Fourth and last line
```

I want to print the first 3 lines, easy:

```
$ sed -n '1,3p' file
> First line
> Second line
> Third line
```

Now I want to print from the occurrence `First` to the occurrence `Third`:

```
$ sed -n '/First/,/Third/p' file
> First line
> Second line
> Third line
> First line
> Second line
> Third line
```

Ah! Not quite what I wanted, I want only the first occurrence of the matched pattern range. How can I do that when I have regex' as my addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append the end-pattern as a quit condition:

```
sed -n '/First/,/Third/p; /Third/q' file
```

Output:

```
> First line
> Second line
> Third line
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this with `awk`

```
awk '!f; /Third/ {f=1}' file
> First line
> Second line
> Third line
```

---

Or even shorter and better, since it stops processing file after found.

```
awk '1; /Third/ {exit}' file
```

---

Or if its needed to take from `first` to `third`

```
awk '/First/ {f=1} f; /Third/ {exit}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed -n '/First/{:loop; $!N; /Third/{p;q}; b loop;}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe awk may help you to do this

```
  awk '/First/{found=1} found{print; if(/Third/) exit}' file
```